# webpack cannot resolve external typescript declaration files

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

Angular2+Webpack, Typescrip@2.1.4, Visual Studio 2015 as IDE.

I need to add external declaration file(name it `extlib`) into my project, which is not provided in `@types` packages. I have did following things:

1. move `extlib.d.ts` to  `typings/extlib/index.d.ts`;
2. modify `tsconfig.json` as follow;

   ```
   {
   "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "module": "es2015",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "removeComments": true,
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "skipLibCheck": true,
       "lib": [
       "es2015",
       "dom"
       ],
       "typeRoots": [
       "./node_modules/@types",
       "./typings"
       ],
       "types": [
       "node",
       "howler",
       "extlib"
       ]
   },
   "files": [
       "app/app.module.ts",
       "main.ts"
   ],
   "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
       "useWebpackText": true
   },
   "compileOnSave": false,
   "buildOnSave": false
   }
   ```
3. use `extlib` in ts files as:

   ```
   import * as extlib from 'extlib'
   ```

After doing this, intellisense of VS works well, so does tsc. But when I use webpack, it told me:

```
    `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'extlib' in '...'`
```

What should I do to make webpack resolve this external typescript declaration files?

Comment: import 'extlib';